# How to add dynamically a package in the manifest.xml file in python?

Tags: ros, python, dependencies

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,
I program in python and javascript.
Firstly, my node make a list of all published topics and their types.
Then, after a human interaction in JavaScript, it subscribes to a topic and imports the library necessary to define the subscriber.
My question is how include this package in the manifest.xml file of this node during its execution.

Waiting for earing from u,

Have fun with ROS

Benoit

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/12734/how-to-add-dynamically-a-package-in-the-manifest.xml-file-in-python?/) by [BeuBeu](https://answers.ros.org/users/329/beubeu/) on ROS Answers with karma: 56 on 2012-01-24

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

you can call `roslib.load_manifest(package_name)` of any package to add it to the sys.path of your node's execution.

---

Originally posted by [kwc](https://answers.ros.org/users/11/kwc/) with karma: 12244 on 2012-01-24

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 4

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [BeuBeu](https://answers.ros.org/users/329/beubeu/) on 2012-01-24**:
Works perfectly. Thank you